# Using a macro as value of addtotoc in \includepdf

Tags: macros, errors, pdfpages, key-value

I would like to include pages from an external PDF file into my document, using the `pdfpages` package. The following works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\clearpage

This is my document, and an included file starts on the next page.

\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,section,1,{A Title},sec.1},3,subsection,2,{A subsection},{s.1.1}]{LF426-2up.pdf}

\end{document}
```

But if the toc entry list was given passed as a macro instead, I get an error:

```
\newcommand{\mylist}{1,section,1,{A Title},s.1,3,subsection,2,{A subsection},{s.1.1}}
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={\mylist}]{otherfile.pdf}
```

> ```
> Runaway argument?
> \END \fi \whiledo {\AM@page =\AM@toc@page }{\ifx \AM@toclist \empty \else \ETC.
> ! Paragraph ended before
> \AM@parse@toclisti was complete.
> <to be read again>
>                     \par
> l.12
>
> ?
> ```

How (if possible) can I pass `\mylist` correctly to the `addtotoc` option of `\includepdf`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
% Put this in the preamble
\newcommand{\eincludepdf}[1][]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\includepdf[#1]}\x}

% this can go everywhere (notice the `\unexpanded` to avoid possible problems)
\newcommand{\mylist}{\unexpanded{1,section,1,{A Title},s.1,3,%
  subsection,2,{A subsection},{s.1.1}}}

% With this you include the PDF file
\eincludepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={\mylist}]{otherfile.pdf}
```

The reason is that the option `addtotoc` expects a comma separated list of values and *not* a macro expanding to that.

### A couple of words about `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup`

This has already been explained elsewhere, but for the sake of completeness, I'll repeat here. When LaTeX finds `\eincludepdf` it looks for a possible `[` following and, if it finds one, gathers what's between `[` and `]` as an argument to replace `#1` (if there's no `[` then `#1` is replaced by nothing). So, with `\eincludepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={\mylist}]` the replacement is

```
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={\mylist}]}\x
```

The fun begins: TeX executes `\begingroup`, thus entering in a "semisimple group", and proceeds to do the `\edef\x`. First of all it expands everything it finds in the following pair of braces:

- `\endgroup` is not expandable, so it remains untouched;
- `\noexpand` *is* expandable, its expansion is empty and the following token becomes unexpandable;
- `[pages=-,addtotoc={` are all unexpandable;
- `\mylist` is expanded to `\unexpanded{...}`, and also `\unexpanded` is expanded, which gives `...` not subject to further expansion (it might contain text with typesetting directives such as `\textbf`, so we protect against its expansion);
- `}]` are not expandable.

Now the meaning of `\x` is assigned: `\endgroup\includepdf[...]` and `\x` is expanded! This closes the group (so removing the meaning of `\x`) and TeX is confronted with

```
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={<contents of \mylist>}]{otherfile.pdf}
```

Et voilà.

Comment: I'm sure you've explained expansion and grouping umpteenth times elsewhere, but could you do me a favor and elaborate why a `{` can come between `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` in your definition of `\eincludepdf`? I'm still puzzled after half a day.

Comment: Why I get an error when I use inside `\mylist` the command `$\boldsymbol{}$` ?

Comment: @LlavDem Well, it's a bit difficult to diagnose, with so few details. Anyway, load `\usepackage{bm}` *after* `\usepackage{amsmath}` and retry. It may be necessary to use `\protect\boldsymbol`, though.