# Macro expanding to comma separated list

Tags: macros, expansion, pgfplotstable, comma-separated-list

I'm trying to use a macro for `pgfplotstable` labels but the macro is treated as a single entry of a csl rather than a csl.

The Question asked in [Using a macro as value of addtotoc in \includepdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50215/using-a-macro-as-value-of-addtotoc-in-includepdf) answered my question but I'm not able to do the same.

`test.csv`:

```
category, value, value 2
cat a,  1,  7
cat b,  2,  6
cat c,  3,  5
cat d,  4,  4
cat e,  5,  3
cat f,  6,  2
cat g,  7,  1
```

The code:

```
\def\blah{a,b,c,d,e,f,g}

\def\plotTable{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar,
                 ymin=0,
                 xlabel=X Label,
                 ylabel=Y Label,
                 xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex},
                 xtick=data,
                 xticklabels={\blah},
                 nodes near coords,
                 nodes near coords align={vertical},
                 width=80mm,
                 height=80mm,
                 area legend,
                 legend pos=outer north east,
                 legend entries={a,b},
                 bar width=3mm]
      \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y=value, col sep=comma] {test.csv};
      \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y=value 2, col sep=comma] {test.csv};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Manually typing out

```
xticklabels={a,b,c,d,e,f,g},
```

shows the labels for each column (rather than clustered to label the first column)

Is there an easy way to be able to put a macro there?

Thanks

Comment: Use `xticklabels/.expand once=\blah` instead of just `xticklabels=\blah`

Comment: @Jake You my friend, are awesome!

Answer (score 3):

@Jake had the answer in the comment:

> Use `xticklabels/.expand once=\blah` instead of `xticklabels=\blah`

Thanks!