# How to insert commas as value of \addtotoc in \includepdf command?

Tags: errors, pdfpages

I would like to include an external PDF file into my document, using the `pdfpages` package. Here is my root file which works fine:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand{\pdf}[3]{
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}},addtotoc={1,chapter,1,#1 \\ #2,#1}
]{#3}
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pdf{The title of the included file}{University of Bar}{otherfile.pdf}
\end{document}
```

But if I insert a comma in the first or second argument of the `\pdf` command (e.g. `University of Bar, Foo`) , I'll get the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
\END \fi \fi \ifthenelse {\AM@page =\AM@toc@page }\@whiledotrue \@whiledofalse 
\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \AM@parse@toclisti.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50215/using-a-macro-as-value-of-addtotoc-in-includepdf/50217#50217), I saw a solution, but I can't apply it to my problem. **Could you please help me to  avoid the above error?**

Comment: did you try an additional pair of braces?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, it didn't work!

Comment: Use `{#1}\\{#2}` in the definition of `\pdf`.

Comment: @egreg: I'm still getting the error:-(

Comment: @egreg: I found the solution: It should be `{#1} \\ {#2},{#1}`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @egreg above, I found the solution: It should be `{#1} \\ {#2},{#1}`.

Comment: This solution gives me tones of problems --for instance, when the page in question contains several other subsections. I can't believe there isn't anything easier.