# Using zpageref in includepdf

Tags: pdfpages, zref

I wanted to extract the appendix from an external pdf document automatically by using `\zpageref` to get the page number specified by the label `sec:appendix` in `paper.tex` (the source of `paper.pdf`). However, the following code didn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{zref-xr,zref-user}
\zexternaldocument*{paper}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=\zpageref{sec:appendix}-last]{paper.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I also followed the solution from [a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50215/using-a-macro-as-value-of-addtotoc-in-includepdf) as below but still got errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{zref-xr,zref-user}
\zexternaldocument*{paper}
\newcommand{\eincludepdf}[1][]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\includepdf[#1]}\x}
\newcommand{\pagenum}{\zpageref{sec:appendix}}
\begin{document}
\eincludepdf[pages={\pagenum}-last]{paper.pdf}
\end{document}
```

How to get this to work? Alternatively, are there any better solution to automate this particular task? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `xr` and `refcount`.

Here's the file `steve-paper.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\kant[1-20]
\section{Two}
\kant[21-40]

\clearpage
\appendix

\section{APP}\label{sec:appendix}
\kant[41-60]

\end{document}
```

And here's the file for the inclusion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xr,refcount}

\externaldocument{steve-paper}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=\getpagerefnumber{sec:appendix}-last]{steve-paper.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, @egreg. It works like a charm! By the way, based on the suggestion, I find this might also be useful if someone wants to extract the pages before the appendix: 
`\includepdf[pages=1-{\the\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{sec:appendix}-1}]{paper.pdf}`